# how to set size for lightning experience visualforce action

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience, publisher-action

when you create a new action where you show a visualforce page, it seems you can only set the height and that there is no way to control the width?
Are there any workarounds for this? Or other ways of doing this?

What I'm doing now is just opening the VF page through a custom button instead of as an action but opening that page in a modal like it happens with actions looks better. (only if we could let's say choose the size of the modal, being medium / large etc)

Comment: Take a look at your CSS for the page. I'd expect you'd be able to control the percentage of the page or how many "grids" the VisualForce page will occupy. Similarly, if you set the Visualforce page to a fixed width using a Div tag, that might also help you with the issue you're having.

Comment: tried these things already but no luck with anything on this level so far. You're also limited in what you can do since SF puts the VF page in an iframe when in the context of a VF quick action & lightning experience.

Comment: Yes, am aware of the lightning I frame. I'd think there'd be CSS you could use in your lightning page for placement of that I-frame. Take a look at the App Builder when you add VisualForce page to lightning page to see the mark-up that get's generated for it and see if it gives you any hints on how to identify and create CSS for it to add to your page.